# $PATH issues with OSX Lion

Tags: macos, terminal, osx-lion, mysql, path

I'm having some issues with running mysql from terminal:

```
macmini:~ michael$ which mysql
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql
macmini:~ michael$ mysql
-bash: /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql: No such file or directory
```

I had a previous installation at /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql which no longer exists.

My path variable is as follows:

```
macmini:~ michael$ echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin:/usr/texbin
```

Dropping to root seems to function correctly:

```
macmini:~ michael$ sudo bash
Password:
bash-3.2# mysql
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 66
Server version: 5.1.44 Source distribution

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

I seem to have found the issue - but I'm not sure how to change or remove this alias

```
macmini:~ michael$ type -a mysql
mysql is aliased to `/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql'
mysql is /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql
mysql is /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql
```

Comment: there's no link, calling its full path works fine, the mysql from sudo bash is the one within XAMPP

Comment: Does `which -a mysql` still show the old executable?

Comment: it displays these: `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql`,`/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin//mysql` 2nd one looks fishy!

Comment: It does look weird indeed. There should be only one of these – although there's still no reference to your `/usr/local/mysql` remainders. Have you *completely* deleted that one? And, maybe logged out and back in?

Comment: I've found the issue using `type -a mysql` - now I just need to work out how to remove this first entry!

Answer (score 3):

Check `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.profile` for a command like this:

```
alias mysql='/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql'
```

Remove it, then reload the shell.

Comment: I don't have a .bash_profile, all that's in my .profile is: `export PATH=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin:$PATH`

Comment: Per `man bash` there are only `/etc/profile`, `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.profile` which bash would read in your case. Are you sure you haven't sourced any other configuration files? If you haven't modified any of those files, then I have no idea where that alias is coming from. Have you reloaded your terminal in between? Does it work when you `unalias mysql`?

Comment: Note that this won't last forever though — if that alias is created again, you'll have to unalias it every time. You can add the `unalias` to one of the shell's startup scripts, but that'll only cure the symptoms, not the cause. You could search all your files for `alias` to see where it's set though.

Answer (score 0):

Try `hash mysql` or `hash -r` to clear the command lookup structure:

> hash [-lr] [-p filename] [-dt] [name]
>
> For each name, the full file name of the command is determined by searching the directories in $PATH and remembered.  If the -p option is supplied, no path search is performed, and filename is used as the full file name of the command.  The -r option causes the shell to forget all remembered  locations.   The  -d option  causes  the shell to forget the remembered location of each name.  If the -t option is supplied, the full pathname to which each name corresponds is printed.  If multiple name  arguments  are  supplied with  -t,  the  name is printed before the hashed full pathname.  The -l option causes output to be displayed in a format that may be reused as input.  If no arguments are given, or if only -l  is  supplied, information  about remembered commands is printed.  The return status is true unless a name is not found or an invalid option is supplied.

Note that you can use `hash -t mysql` to verify if the cached path lookup is indeed incorrect.

If `hash -t` shows that the correct path would be chosen and things still don't work, the next step is to check for aliases and functions. Test for an alias with:

```
alias mysql
```

This will either print `-bash: alias: mysql: not found` or show the alias definition. If there is a `mysql` alias defined, you'll have to grep for it in the `~/.bash*`, `~/.profile` and `/etc/profile` files.

Check for a bash function definition with:

```
shopt -s extdebug
typeset -fF mysql
shopt -u extdebug
```

This sets the `extdebug` shell option, then asks bash for the function `mysql` which, if it exists, will include where it is defined as `mysql 42 /Users/foo/.bash_profile` or similar (function name, line number, file).

If there is an alias or function, remove it from the file defining it and optionally remove it from the current shell with:

```
unalias mysql
unset -f mysql
```

`unalias` removes an alias definition, `unset -f` a function definition.

Comment: No luck :( `macmini:~ michael$ hash mysql
macmini:~ michael$ mysql
-bash: /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql: No such file or directory
macmini:~ michael$ hash -r
macmini:~ michael$ mysql
-bash: /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql: No such file or directory
macmini:~ michael$ hash -t mysql
-bash: hash: mysql: not found`

Comment: And what if you set a full path with `hash -p /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql mysql`?

Comment: `macmini:~ michael$ hash -t mysql
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql` it now displays, but running `mysql` results in the same error

Comment: Then this is not a bash or path error.

Comment: what else could it be? running `macmini:~ michael$ /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
...` directly works fine